# Unable to Set Element Attribute Using jQuery data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I'm having trouble updating elements from JavaScript. My project is fairly complex but here's a tiny piece of it:

```
myWebService(/*...*/)
.done(function (result) {
    var newRows = $(rows).clone();
    $('#drop-placeholder').after(newRows);
    $(newRows).data('test', 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ');
}
```

Using Chrome, I can watch these statements execute. However, with `newRows` in the watch window, I can see that the attribute never gets added/updated. And, sure enough, after the call is done, I don't see the specified attribute on my page.

Can anyone see what I might be missing. `rows` (and therefore `newRows`) represents any number of table row elements.

Comment: FYI, `newRows` is already a jQuery object. You don't have to pass it to jQuery *again*. What do yo mean by *"I don't see the specified attribute on my page"*? How are you trying to "see" it?

Comment: Are you saying I can just do `newRows.data()`? I thought `$()` gave me additional options. (I was trying to see it by examining the elements in Chrome.)

Comment: Yep. `.clone` returns a jQuery object, as does `$()`. If you already have a jQuery object, you don't have to pass it to `$()` again (the same might be for `rows`, but I don't know what it is). You usually do `$('div')` instead of `$($('div'))` right? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.data()` sets background data that is handled purely by jQuery - it does not set HTML attributes.

If you are trying to set an attribute such as `data-test` in `<div data-test="stuff"></div>` you need to use `.attr("data-test", variable)`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I never realized this. Working now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The setting the `data` via jQuery `.data()` *does not* set the attribute, only the underlying data store.  If you want to change the attribute, you have to use `.attr()`.